# Get Distinct Count of Values based on conditions in other columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get a distinct count of values that is uniquely based on the conditions of the other columns.

Below is the data

```
Month   Homes   Type
Jul     HH1     Cat1
Jul     HH2     Cat2
Jul     HH2     Cat3
Jul     HH3     Cat2
Jul     HH4     Cat3
Jul     HH5     Cat2
Jul     HH6     Cat2
Jul     HH6     Cat3
Jul     HH7     Cat2
Jul     HH8     Cat3
Jul     HH9     Cat1
```

I need to find a unique count of Homes that are exclusive to a single Type. I have the data at a monthly level and need to group by the month, the final desired output is as follows -

```
Month   Cat1    Cat2    Cat3    Cat1+Cat2   Cat2+Cat3   Cat3+Cat1
Jul       2       3      2           0          2           0
```

So, for Cat 1 there are two homes (HH1, HH9) that are exclusively part of Cat1. Similarly,
Cat 2 (HH5, HH6, HH7) has 3 Homes
Cat 3 (HH4, HH8) has 2 Homes.

The next is the combinations of Types -
Cat2+Cat3 has 2 homes
There are no homes that are exclusively part of both Cat3 and Cat1.

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate twice, once by `month` and `homes` and the second time just by month:

```
select month,
       sum(has_cat1) as cat1,
       sum(has_cat2) as cat2,
       sum(has_cat3) as cat3,
       sum(has_cat1 * has_cat2) as cat12,
       sum(has_cat1 * has_cat3) as cat13,
       sum(has_cat2 * has_cat3) as cat23
from (select month, homes,
             max(case when cat = 'cat1' then 1 else 0 end) as has_cat1,
             max(case when cat = 'cat2' then 1 else 0 end) as has_cat2,
             sum(case when cat = 'cat3' then 1 else 0 end) as has_cat3
      from t
      group by month, homes
     ) mh
group by month;
```

EDIT:

If you want the first three columns be be exactly singletons, you can just tweak the arithmetic:

```
select month,
       sum(has_cat1 * (1 - has_cat2) * (1 - has_cat3)) as cat1,
       sum(has_cat2 * (1 - has_cat1) * (1 - has_cat3)) as cat2,
       sum(has_cat3 * (1 - has_cat1) * (1 - has_cat2)) as cat3,
       sum(has_cat1 * has_cat2 * (1 - has_cat3)) as cat12,
       sum(has_cat1 * has_cat3 * (1 - has_cat2)) as cat13,
       sum(has_cat2 * has_cat3 * (1 - has_cat1)) as cat23
from (select month, homes,
             max(case when Type = 'Cat1' then 1 else 0 end) as has_cat1,
             max(case when Type = 'Cat2' then 1 else 0 end) as has_cat2,
             sum(case when Type = 'Cat3' then 1 else 0 end) as has_cat3
      from Table1 
      group by month, homes
     ) mh
group by month;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e493265feb5a75ceb4c7c0384b143962) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: The count of homes aligns for the multiple categories (cat12),(cat13),(cat23). But the counts for an individual category show duplicates. Below is the SQL fiddle link
[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3240d/1/0)

Comment: @ExelIQ . . . I would normally want any home in `cat1`, regardless of other categories.  That is what the first query does.  The second query gets exact singletons and doubletons.  This version will not count a home that has all three categories.